# Download xls file from url

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unable to download a xls file from a url. I have tried with both `urlopen` and `urlretrive`. But I recieve an really long error message starting with:

- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Henrik/Documents/Development/Python/Projects/ImportFromWeb.py", line 6, in 
  f = ur.urlopen(dls)
- File "C:\Users\Henrik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

and ending with:

- urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
  The last 30x error message was:
  Found

Unfortionally I can't provide the url I am using since the data is sensitive. However I will give you the url with some parts removed.

- https://xxxx.xxxx.com/xxxxlogistics/w/functions/transportinvoicelist?0-8.IBehaviorListener.2-ListPageForm-table-TableForm-exportToolbar-xlsExport&antiCache=1477160491504

As you can see the url dosn't end with a "/file.xls" for example. I don't know if that matters but most of the threds regarding this issue has had those types of links.

If I enter the url in my address bar the download file window appears:
[Image of download window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od1xh.jpg)

The code I have written look like this:

```
import urllib.request as ur
import openpyxl as pyxl

dls = 'https://xxxx.xxxx.com/xxxxlogistics/w/functions/transportinvoicelist?0-8.IBehaviorListener.2-ListPageForm-table-TableForm-exportToolbar-xlsExport&antiCache=1477160491504'

f = ur.urlopen(dls)
```

I am grateful for any help you can provide!

Comment: You aware of what HTTP 302 code means, don't you?

Comment: I suggest you to use famous [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, if these errors make problem to you

Comment: Thx agg3l, I will look at the requests library. About the HTTP 302 code, what is it I don't? I don't have access through that url even through the address bar? Because that was the first i tried, I ran it in comand prompt after I got that error message, and I got access.